# techniques of asynchronous tasks

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, callback, android-asynctask

Ho do you perform asynchronous tasks and notify about their finishing?
I see the next approaches(they are related, but...) for doing it:

1. AsynchTask (SwingWorkerTask) where there are the such methods like
   onPre() and onPost() with dispatching data to the UI thread
2. Callbacks/Delegates/Notifications(Notification Center)
3. Executor, Callable, Future (maybe)

What is the better choice for writing for example a mobile Rest client?
What technique do you use in your apps?

Comment: Would you mind removing "thanks to Alex"? You may put thanks to Goetz, Bloch and the Java Sun/Oracle team instead.

Comment: Is something wrong with this question?

Comment: Well, according to the FAQ, StackOverflow wants questions that can be answered, not discussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use Guava [ListenableFuture](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) for such tasks. It simplifies almost every concurrent task I need because I don't have to worry about many things in concurrency.

Also, as explained in the link:

> The most important reason to use ListenableFuture is that it becomes
>   possible to have complex chains of asynchronous operations.